# mysqldump produces output, but phpmyadmin won't import it?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've written a PHP script to dump my database using the following:

```
system("mysqldump -h".$dbservername." -u".$dbusername." -p".$dbpassword." ".$dbname." > backup.sql");
readfile("backup.sql");
```

This works fine, and my Java client code

```
                final String output = doPost("mydomain/getdb.php");

                try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/home/user/desktop/backup.sql")) {
                    out.println(output);
                    out.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    // do something...
                }
```

works fine. The output looks like what I would expect, e.g.

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.39, for Linux (x86_64)---- Host: localhost    Database: mydomain_mydb-- -------------------------------------------------------- Server version    5.6.39-cll-lve/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;---- Table structure for table `Projects`--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Projects`;/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;CREATE TABLE `Projects` (  `jobno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `state` int(11) NOT NULL, ... etc ...
```

(although it's all on one line, rather than nicely formatted into lines)

Anyway, when I then try to import this `.sql` file back into PHPMyAdmin, in a freshly created new database (no tables etc), it works without error, but does not add any tables or data. I get the green (as in nothing went wrong) message:

> Import has been successfully finished, 1 query executed. (backup.sql)

and

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0005 seconds.)

Any ideas what might be wrong?

PS for some reason I can't add the `mysqldump` tag...

Answer (score 0):

I now know what's wrong. I just tried to import the `backup.sql` directly from my server, and that works fine.

The problem is my client is receiving the data as a single string with no carriage returns.

The following client-side download code works:

```
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(filename)));

        int c;

        while ((c = buffer.read()) != -1) {
            writer.write((char) c);
        }

        writer.close();
        buffer.close();
        conn.disconnect();
```